# Checking HTTP Status code django

Tags: django, request, httprequest

I am probably staring it right in the face here. But does Django have a way of actually checking what the HTTP Status code is. I'm basically interested if it's the 302 redirect status code. But no matter what I try and search for I'm only getting HTTPResponse() which is no good to me.

Comment: Do you mean in a unittest or what? Response.status_code (or whatever you name your response variable) should get it.

Comment: No not in a unittest, this is what I keep getting when I search google for this situation. I purely just want to get the status code within a view.

Comment: I don't think there is a status code for a request, only for a response. Why do you need it in the view?

Comment: I'm trying to see if a view is being accessed via a redirect or if they have directly gone to the page.

Comment: Do you know where it would be redirected from? You could do `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None)` to see where it was referred from (if anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question unfortunately doesn't make any sense. The reason why you don't get any Google results for this is that there's simply no such thing as a status code for a request. The status code is what the server sends back to the client as a result of the request: it's unavoidably part of the response, not the request.

I suspect however that this is an XY problem. What, exactly, are you trying to achieve? If you need some data to be preserved through a redirect, then you probably want to store it in the session.

Comment: I'm trying to check in the view if the view has been accessed directly or as a redirect, as we only wish the view to be access if it's been redirected to.

Comment: As I say, then, you should store something in the session in the originating view, then check it in the new view: if it's there, you can be sure it's a redirect.